# OAuth throws "missing code validator" in Google OAuth2

Tags: python, flask, google-oauth

I am following [this example](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) in an attempt to authenticate my users with the Google API.
Here is the relevant code I am using, almost exactly as in the example:

```py
@app.route('/login/')
def login():
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        'client_secret.json',
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'])
    flow.redirect_uri = 'https://localhost:5000/oauth2callback/'
    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
        access_type='offline',
    include_granted_scopes='true')
    session['state'] = state
    return redirect(authorization_url)

#called by Google's oauth 
@app.route('/oauth2callback/')
def oauth2callback():
    state = request.args['state']
    # Use the client_secret.json file to identify the application requesting
    # authorization. The client ID (from that file) and access scopes are required.
    state = session['state']
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        'client_secret.json',
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'],
        state=state)
    flow.redirect_uri = url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)

    authorization_response = request.url
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response, code_verifier=False)
```

When I do this, it gives the error,
`oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidGrantError: (invalid_grant) Missing code verifier.`

I do not know what a code verifier is, nor did the examples mention one.

The stack trace is available if anyone thinks it will help

How can I solve this issue?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I get the same error when using `google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.0`. However, the error does not appear in `0.3.0`. So I guess that something has changed in `0.4.0`.

Comment: A related upstream issue: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python-oauthlib/issues/46

Comment: Well, stackoverflow to the rescue again. `pip uninstall google-oauth-lib && pip install google-oauth-lib==0.3.0` has solved this issue. Should I post this as an answer? It feels... hacky. Is google's package just broken? How can I add a valid code_verifier?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the 0.4.0 version of `google-auth-oauthlib` (see [this upstream issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python-oauthlib/issues/46); note that it has been reported after this SO question was posted).

You have the following options:

1. As a workaround, you can downgrade the used version:

   ```
   pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib==0.3.0
   ```
2. Pass a custom code verifier when instantiating `google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow()`, which [should be](https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html#google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow) a random string of 43-128 characters used to verify the key exchange using [PKCE](https://oauth.net/2/pkce/):

   ```py
   oauth2_session, client_config = google_auth_oauthlib.helpers.session_from_client_secrets_file(
       'client_secret.json',
       scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']),
   )
   flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow(
       oauth2_session,
       client_type='web',
       client_config=client_config,
       redirect_uri='https://localhost:5000/oauth2callback/',
       code_verifier='<random string>'
   )
   ```

   Note: The code is for your `login()` function. You will have to slightly adjust it to work in your `oauth2callback()` function.
3. Wait until the bug is fixed in upstream (provided that it is a bug). After that, the code verifier will be auto-generated when not provided.

Comment: The verifier can also be set after construction (either constructor or class method): ```flow.code_verifier = '<random string>'```

Comment: The answer from @Jerther seems more valid, as it is a random string.  Creating your own is more overhead or a shortcut using hash or a constant which lowers security.

Comment: Agree with @PaulKenjora ... plus the bug has been fixed. I'm now using 1.1.0 which works if you provide a valid `code_verifier`, a bonus if the library can take the responsibility with a single flag.

Answer (score 5):

Based on s3rvac's answer, I dug a bit into the source code and found that the `code_verifier` property can in fact be auto generated in the [`authorization_url()`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python-oauthlib/blob/e56853e0b29e4b67943e2dd7cc361dea5eb94d2e/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py#L220) method! So no need to generate one yourself.

First when you first construct the Flow object, you must enable `autogenerate_code_verifier`:

```
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        'client_secret.json',
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'],
        autogenerate_code_verifier=True  # <-- ADD THIS HERE
)
```

Then in your `login()` method, after the call to `flow.authorization_url()`, store `flow.code_verifier` in the session:

```
authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
        access_type='offline', 
        include_granted_scopes='true')  # code_verifier is set in this method
session['code_verifier'] = flow.code_verifier  # Get and store the code
session['state'] = state
return redirect(authorization_url)
```

Then, in the callback method, just load it back:

```
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow(
    oauth2_session,
    client_type='web',
    client_config=client_config,
    redirect_uri='https://localhost:5000/oauth2callback/',
    code_verifier=session.get('code_verifier')  # Load the code. Don't set autogenerate_code_verifier here, otherwise code_verifier would be overwritten.
)
```

I use `Flow.from_client_config()` to construct a `Flow` but I just add this line and it works fine:

```
flow.code_verifier = session.get('code_verifier')
```

Comment: Worked as described.  Probably more secure this way as each auth flow has a unique session.

Comment: Apparently, the next code change to flow.py that happened like a month after I originally posted this answer was to remove the automatic generation of code_verifier by default, and add a flag to enable it. I updated my answer to reflect that.